# ArgoCD bootstrapping with terraform in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, terraform, argocd

I am trying to deploy ArgoCD and applications located in subfolders through Terraform in an AKS cluster.

This is my Folder structure tree:

*I'm using app of apps approach, so first I will deploy ArgoCD (this will manage itself as well) and later ArgoCD will let me SYNC the cluster-addons and application manually once installed.*

```
apps
   cluster-addons
      AKV2K8S
      Cert-Manager
      Ingress-nginx
   application
      application-A
argocd
   override-values.yaml
   Chart
```

When I run the command "helm install ..." manually in the AKS cluster everything is installed fine.
ArgoCD is installed and later when I access ArgoCD I see that rest of applications are missing and I can sync them manually.

**However, If I want to install it through Terraform only ArgoCD is installed but looks like it does not "detect" the override_values.yaml file**:

i mean, ArgoCD and ArgoCD application set controller are installed in the cluster but ArgoCD does not "detect" the values.yaml files that are customized for my AKS cluster. If I run "helm install" manually on the cluster everything works but not through Terraform

```
resource "helm_release" "argocd_applicationset" {
  name       = "argocd-applicationset"
  repository = https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
  chart      = "argocd-applicationset"
  namespace  = "argocd"
  version    = "1.11.0"
}

resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
  name       = "argocd"
  repository = https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
  chart      = "argo-cd"
  namespace  = "argocd"
  version    = "3.33.6"
  values = [
    "${file("values.yaml")}"
  ]
```

values.yaml file is located in the folder where I have the TF code to install argocd and argocd applicationset.

I tried to change the name of the file" values.yaml" to "override_values.yaml" but same issue.

**I have many things changed into the override_values.yaml file so I cannot use "set" inside the TF code...**

Also, I tried adding:

```
 values = [
    "${yamlencode(file("values.yaml"))}"
  ]
```

but I get this error in "apply" step in the pipeline:

```
error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {} "argo-cd:\r\n  ## ArgoCD configuration\r\n  ## Ref: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd\r\n
```

Probably because is not a JSON file? It does make sense to convert this file into a JSON one?

Any idea if I can pass this override values yaml file through terraform?

If not, please may you post a clear/full example with mock variables on how to do that using Azure pipeline?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with `yamlencode(file("values.yaml"))`.

Comment: @MarkoE I've added --> "values = [ "${yamlencode(file("values.yaml"))}" ]" but I get this error in "apply" step --> "error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {} "argo-cd:\r\n ## ArgoCD configuration\r\n ## Ref: github.com/argoproj/argo-cd\r\n" Probably because the file is YAML. values.yaml file is a correct valid yaml file as when I apply it manually it's working. Should I convert this YAML file into a JSON one?

Comment: Uhm, how about `yamldecode`?

Comment: @MarkoE, I added --> "values = ["${yamldecode(file("values.yaml"))}"]" but getting an error in "plan" step this time -->  "values = [4m[[0m
"${yamldecode(file("values.yaml"))}"[0m
Inappropriate value for attribute "values": element 0: string required.
2022-03-06T##[error]Error: The process 'D:\Agents\Agentx\_work\_tool\terraform\0.13.0\x64\terraform.exe' failed with exit code 1"

Comment: Btw, which version of Terraform are you using? The new syntax does not require quoting, maybe that is what is causing the original issue. Can you retry with `values = [ file("values.yaml") ]`?

Comment: @MarkoE I'm using version 0.13. However, I did not have problems with my original code with values when quoting except that looked like argocd was ignoring the "values.yaml" file. My question is: Is it possible to pass an override-values.yaml file through "values block" in terraform when installing ArgoCD so I can "detect" the applications in my repo so later I can SYNC them manually? (basically the same when I am installing ArgoCD manually in my AKS cluster through helm) Also, please may you let me know how you would write the "values code" using this new syntax? Thanks

Comment: I did, the last part of my previous comment. :)

Comment: The issue was the identation finally... I was not getting any issue but it was the identation... I will post the correct code soon.

Comment: That's what YML does to people. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the values identation in TF code.

The issue was resolved when I resolve that:

```
resource "helm_release" "argocd_applicationset" {
  name       = "argocd-applicationset"
  repository = https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
  chart      = "argocd-applicationset"
  namespace  = "argocd"
  version    = "1.11.0"
}

resource "helm_release" "argocd" {
  name       = "argocd"
  repository = https://argoproj.github.io/argo-helm
  chart      = "argo-cd"
  namespace  = "argocd"
  version    = "3.33.6"
  values = [file("values.yaml")]
```

It is working fine also with quoting.